# NextJs page won't render due to AdBlock

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel, adblock

I'm working on a NextJs app that was upgraded from v11 to v12.  It's pulling data/rending pages from the cloud CMS platform, ContentStack. One of the pages that gets rendered, */privacy-policy*, is being blocked by AdBlockers.  I confirmed this by turning off AdBlockers and checking in Incognito mode.

The console log in devtools reports the following: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

I'm unsure how to approach this scenario, as */privacy-policy* has legal and SEO implications to it.

Is there a way to ensure that all of the pages will render?

Comment: This is unlikely to be Next.js specific. There must be a way to "debug" what is triggering the adblock (if the content, the path, hostname, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

For me this is caused by a uBlock Origin Filter called "EasyList Cookie".

It blocks the /privacy-policy.js file from loading from `http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/privacy-policy.js`

It's not one of the default uBlock Origin filters and you can turn it off in Settings > Filter Lists > Annoyances > Untick EasyList Cookie.